# mongodb $or always return false (const)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I make an aggregation pipeline to retrive documents and add a new field "expired" (boolean), its value is based on the field "expireAt" (Date)

the expired field considerd true if:

- expiredAt is missing or null or empty
- expiredAt < now

this is my trial:

```
{project:
expired: {
          $not: {
            $or: [{ expireAt: null }, { $gte: ['$expireAt', new Date()] }]
          }
        }
}
```

this code always give me false even if the document has an expireAt value whitch is < now

by performing explain:

```
{ '$project': { _id: true, expireAt: true, expired: { '$cons
    t': false } } }
```

query result:

- note the expireAt field and the corresponding expired value
- today is: 27/11/2018

  { expired: false },
  { expireAt: 2019-07-15T17:18:11.000Z, expired: false },
  { expireAt: 2017-07-16T17:18:11.000Z, expired: false },

also {expireAt:{$exists:false}} give error:
MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$exists'at queryCallback

any idea to check the existence of the field (weather its value is null or not)

Answer (score 0):

> Use `$cond` operator to achieve

Below query help you :

> I have used `date` in my field.

```
db.getCollection('chat').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      'date': 1,
      "expired": {
        $cond: {
          if: { $gte: ['$date', new Date()] },
          then: false,
          else: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**With `$or`**

```
db.getCollection('chat').aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
          {
            date: 1,
            expired: { $or: [ { $lt: [ "$date", new Date() ] }, { $eq: [ "$date", null ] } ] }
          }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: same result, also don't remove $or

Comment: the updated query (after adding $not) gives true if the expireAt is missing

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked with me:

```
expired:{
$and: ['$expireAt', { $lt: ['$expireAt', new Date()] }]
}
```